# How to create primitive-wrapper object with prototype

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I can wrap a primitive in an object:

```
> p = Object(1);
< Number {[[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
```

which lets me set properties on it:

```
> p.prop = 2;
> p.prop
< 2
```

while still using the primitive object:

```
> p + 1
< 2
```

I want to adorn such primitive-wrapping objects with prototype methods. I know I can set the prototype explicitly with:

```
> Object.setPrototypeOf(p, { q : 3 });
< Number {prop: 2, q: 3, [[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}
```

Is there any way to create wrapper objects with the prototype already in place, so I don't have to set it on each newly created wrapper (or pollute the `Object` prototype)? Perhaps by creating an `ObjectWrapper`, which would work as in:

```
> ObjectWrapper = ...???...
> ObjectWrapper.prototype = { q : 3 };
> [new] ObjectWrapper(1)
```

which I would want to yield

```
< Number {q:3, [[PrimitiveValue]]: 1}function
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this structure...

```
//outer function is to provide support for multiple wrappers with different inheritance
function PrimitiveWrapper(){
        return function(x){
            this.valueOf = function(){
                return x;
            }
        };
    };

var wrapper1 = PrimitiveWrapper();
wrapper1.prototype.p = 3;
var w11 = new wrapper1(1);
var w12 = new wrapper1(2);

var wrapper2 = PrimitiveWrapper();
var w21 = new wrapper2(1);

console.log(w11+3); //4
console.log(w11.p); //3
console.log(w12+3); //5
console.log(w12.p); //3

console.log(w21+3); //4
console.log(w21.p); //undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? You create an `ObjectWrapperCreator` which gives you a function back that you can then call, like:

```
function ObjectWrapperCreator(prototype) {

    var wrapper = function(param) {
        prototype.param = param;
        var obj = Object(param);
        Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, prototype);
        obj.valueOf = function() {
            return this.param;
        };
        return obj;
    };
    return wrapper;
}

Usage:
  var b = ObjectWrapperCreator({p: 1});
  var c = b(4);
  >> c + 1
```

Comment: you could make the param property immutable if you don't want anyone to mess with it immediately after adding it to the prototype.